Git post-receive hook to auto-merge has unexpected behaviour. Prints all files and leaves uncommited changes
I have two separate repos with these branches.

dev-repo

main -> prod-repo/main
dev


prod-repo

main
production



Prod-repo is always on branch "production" and is the running code of the webapp. My workflow to deploy is simple:
From dev-repo:
git checkout main
git merge dev
git push prod-repo

Then, from prod-repo
git checkout production #I understand this is redundant, but "just in case"
git tag -f last-stable
git merge main

(the tag allows me to quickly go back)

To automate this process and deploy when I push main, I made this post-receive hook that I put in prod-repo:
#!/bin/bash

git checkout production
git tag -f last-stable

if git diff --quiet main produccion; then
    echo "No differences"
else
    if git merge main; then
        echo "Successful merge"
    else
        echo "Conflict detected, aborting merge..."
        git merge --abort
    fi
fi


Now, when I git push from dev-repo I see two things that I didn't expect:

Output shows remote: D <file> for every single file in the repo, so it's a freaking long log
When I git status from prod-repo, it suddenly has unstaged changes that perfectly "revert" the changes pushed, meaning the working directory didn't get changed. The branches are merged in git log though.

I was expecting the hook to have the same behaviour as the commands being entered manually, but no. No ChatGPT or other Google search brought light into this.
